# Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I was told by someone else that input this url https://beachbumbookworm.com/service.php into their browser it works. However, when I place the url in my google browser it will not work.

I have been working from a tutorial at this site https://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/#app at 3.2 in the tutorial. There is a service.php file below that I pasted into text editor on my MacBook Air. I have made a table named locations in phpmyadmin, I have given proper permissions for the username and password. There aren't any characters in the password that would warrant a denial. I am using exactly what the tutorial is using, which includes a wordpress + Bluehost environment. From the bluehost there is a control panel I have access to and there, I have accessed phpmyadmin and mysqldatabases. After the service.php file was edited by me, I uploaded it into php per the article. I'm not sure what's wrong, please help.

```
<?php
 
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
 
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
 
// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Locations";
 
// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();
 
    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }
 
    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
 
// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

---

Here is an image of the database table created
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't matter what browser do you use in that case, because MySQL connection creates at the backend before sending the response;
2. At the line with `mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");` code try to replace credentials with that one, which you have used in PhpMyAdmin;
3. Check your MySQL credentials with your MacOS terminal. Use this command: `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: "Command not found" is what I receive in the terminal, I kept "localhost" the same. Tutorial doesn't day to change that one.

Comment: How do you access PhpMyAdmin? Is it installed on your Macbook Air?

Comment: it's through bluehost control panel

Comment: So, if it is not on you PC, you should use it’s address instead of localhost.